# How to select neighboring polygons of equal attribute value

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I need to select neighboring polygons that share the same attribute value I have a polyigonos shapefile that contains a text field that represents a type of coverage, I want to select neighboring polygon that share the same attribute value (coverage). Something similar is done when making a Dissolve but I do not require Dissolve, just knowing that neighboring polygons share the same attribute value.

Comment: first add to selection the spatial neighbor then, remove from selection or select in the selection by attribute.